# Why does alloc not work in applicationWillEnterForeground?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I both put this in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
[MAMapServices sharedServices].apiKey = kMapKey;
_mapView = [[MAMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
self.mapView.delegate = self;
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

and in the delegate method for map, I do this:

```
-(void)mapView:(MAMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MAUserLocation *)userLocation updatingLocation:(BOOL)updatingLocation
{
  if (self.mapView) {
     self.mapView = nil;
  }
}
```

In `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` it works, but in `applicationWillEnterForeground` the _mapView's `alloc` does't work. It's still `nil` after `alloc` and `init`. Why? (By the way, the `_mapView` property is `strong`, not `weak`.)

Comment: You should allocate to self.mapView instead of _mapView.

Comment: Does it matter ? It was self.mapView. I changed it to _mapView for a testing.

Comment: Should matter. The two are not equivalent afak.

Comment: using `self.` for properties accesses the default setter and getter methods for the property which does some stuff extra in the default implementation. where as accessing `_mapView` gives your direct access to the variable itself. accessing the ivar (`_propertyName`) is bad practise for anywhere other then inside `init` method of the owning class. have a read of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Comment: I mean they both don't work here. They were both nil after alloc init.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the instance variable `_mapView` to assign the allocation to.
Try using

```
self.mapView = [[MAMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Is that property weak?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your Delegate.. You are setting it to nil over there

Comment: I updated the question just now. There is nothing more relevant in the delegate.